# Selenium runs Firefox driver for spiders not used in

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I've used Firefox driver of [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load and scrap web pages in some of spiders in my [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) project.

**The problem:**
Selenium runs an instance of Firefox when running all the spiders, event those I've not imported `webdriver` and not called `webdriver.Firefox()` in.

**Expected behavior:**
Selenium runs an instance of Firfox *only* when I run spiders that have been used `webdriver.Firefox()` in.

**Why this is important?**
I'm quiting the Firefox instance after the spider is done, but vividly this is not happening in spiders not using Selenium.

**The spider that is not using Selenium**
This spider is not using Selenium and I expect it not to run Firefox.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MySpider"
    domain = 'www.example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['http://example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.css('.main-content'):
            # Article is a scrapy.item
            item = Article()
            item['title'] = sel.css('h1::text').extract()[0]
            item['body'] = sel.css('p::text').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @JeffC hope it's clear now. thanks

Comment: That doesn't help. Your code shows you instantiating the Firefox browser in the `MySpider` class. Why do you expect that it won't run?

Comment: @JeffC I've tried to explain this is how I've used Selenium ONLY in SOME of spiders which scrap dynamic pages, rest of the spiders don't import, and consequently don't use selenium at all. but still when I run them, an instance of Firefox is being opened

Comment: Then post the code where you *aren't* using Firefox so we can see the non-working code. Showing us working code won't really help us solve the problem.

Comment: @JeffC ok, I replaced it with the code of the spider that's not using Selenium. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was actually in how I was instantiating `webdriver.Firefox` module in spiders that were intended to use Selenium:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # basic scrapy setting
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        result = scrapy.Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        # scrap and yield items to pipeline
        # then in certain condition:
        self.driver.quit()
```

**Why it was happening?**
When running Scrapy commands, python interprets all the classes in project. so no matter which spider I was trying to run, Selenium ran a new instance of `webdriver.Firefox` for each spider class containing this command line.

**Solution**
Just moved webdriver instantiation to class init method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```